# Trying to make a simple program with semaphores

Tags: c, unix, semaphore

I am attempting to create a program that forks child processes that sleep for a few seconds and then releases the semaphore for the parent that is waiting. I've spent days reading about semaphores and researching online but it's all very confusing. Also, every example is a large amount of code for something that seems simple, and each one is completely different.

EDIT: DERP! So, the code doesn't work. The child(ren) forks just fine but the parent is forever stuck on sem_wait. So there appears to be something wrong with how I'm implementing the semaphore.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j, dummy, intCast;
    sem_t s;

    if (argc < 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0){
        printf("Usage: sem_sync X (X is one or more ints)");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    setbuf(stdout, NULL); /* Make stdout unbuffered, since we
                                           terminate child with _exit() */
    printf(" Parent started\n");

    sem_init(&s, 0, 0);
    for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
        switch (fork()) {
        case -1:
            printf("Error on fork %d", j);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        case 0: /* Child */
            intCast = atoi(argv[j]); // Casts the argument into an integer
            printf("Child sleeping for %d seconds\n",intCast);
            sleep(intCast);
            sem_post(&s);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        default: /* Parent loops to create next child */
            break;
        }
    }
    printf(" Parent is waiting\n");
    sem_wait(&s);
    printf(" Parent ready to go\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here's the working code with sem_open() and sem_close()

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j, intCast;
    sem_t *s;

    printf(" Parent started\n");
    s = sem_open("file1", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
    if (s == SEM_FAILED){
        printf("sem_open() failed. errno:\n");
    }

    for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
        switch (fork()) {
        case -1:
            printf("Error on fork %d", j);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0: /* Child */
            intCast = atoi(argv[j]);
            printf("Child sleeping for %d seconds\n",intCast);
            sleep(intCast);
            sem_post(s);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default: 
            break;
        }
    }
    printf(" Parent is waiting\n");
    for (j = 1; j < argc; j++){
        sem_wait(s);
    }
    sem_close(s);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem with this code? is this code seems long to you?

Comment: It would be more useful if you provide a problem as the length of code does not seems an issue of concern.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the post to point out the issue with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sem_open()` instead of `sem_init()`.  The semaphores you create with `sem_init()` are not shared across processes unless you create them in shared memory.  It is much easier to just use `sem_open()` for what you are trying to do.

Edit: Remember that `sem_open()` will create a persistent semaphore that you need to remove with `sem_unlink()`.  If there may be a stray file lying around from a previous invocation, you may want to unlink the file before you open it like this:

```
sem_unlink(filename);
sem_open(filename, O_CREAT, etc...);
```

so that you delete the named semaphore before you open it.  Otherwise, if it already exists, the `sem_open` will open the existing semaphore and inherit whatever count is already in the semaphore.

Comment: Ok, so I changed my code to use sem_open() and now I'm having the opposite problem. The parent wakes up before the child process has a chance to sem_post().

Comment: Not enough space in comments, I'll edit my original post. After switching to sem_open() it was behaving oddly because I didn't have sem_close() and the semaphore would remain through multiple executions.

Comment: Use sem_unlink() to get rid of the semaphore once you are done with it.  Think of it like a file that stays around even after you close your program.  You may just want to put a sem_unlink() right before your sem_open() to make sure the file is deleted.